# UI-Bootstrap Accordion Directive not working

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive

I downloaded the [angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs) UI Bootstrap accordion directive found here: [UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

However, I cannot get it to work and the `<accordion>` tag generates errors.  I included the `['ui.bootstrap']` dependency in my angular module and I put references to files directly on page.  Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

Here is my module:

```
var myApp = angular.module("dashboardManagement", ['ui.bootstrap'])
```

Here is my view:

```
  @section scripts{
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/app/app.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/app/Contractor/contractorController.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/app/Contractor/contractorService.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/ui-bootstrap-custom-tpls-0.13.3.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/app/Test/AccordionDemoCtrl.js"></script>

}
<h2>Index</h2>

<div ng-app="dashboardManagement">

    <div>
        <div>
            <div ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl">
                <p>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="status.open = !status.open">Toggle last panel</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="status.isFirstDisabled = ! status.isFirstDisabled">Enable / Disable first panel</button>
                </p>
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="oneAtATime">
                        Open only one at a time
                    </label>
                </div>
                <accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
                    <accordion-group heading="Static Header, initially expanded" is-open="status.isFirstOpen" is-disabled="status.isFirstDisabled">
                        This content is straight in the template.
                    </accordion-group>
                    <accordion-group heading="{{group.title}}" ng-repeat="group in groups">
                        {{group.content}}
                    </accordion-group>
                    <accordion-group heading="Dynamic Body Content">
                        <p>The body of the accordion group grows to fit the contents</p>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="addItem()">Add Item</button>
                        <div ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</div>
                    </accordion-group>
                    <accordion-group is-open="status.open">
                        <accordion-heading>
                            I can have markup, too! <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': status.open, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !status.open}"></i>
                        </accordion-heading>
                        This is just some content to illustrate fancy headings.
                    </accordion-group>
                </accordion>
            </div>
        </div>
`
```

Answer (score 0):

there's a couple of different issues I can see here. First is, you are including both the minified and unminified versions of these resources, so you have the same code twice. So make sure to just include `<script src="~/Scripts/ui-bootstrap-custom-tpls-0.13.3.js"></script>` and remove the other three similar overlapping scripts. Are you also including Angular above these scripts? because that is a dependency and will throw errors if not included before

second, is the provided example code what you're actually using? Because of course just having this:

```
<accordion>

</accordion>
```

will not do very much. You have to provide content for this directive like:

```
<accordion>
  <accordion-group heading="{{group.title}}" ng-repeat="group in groups">
    {{group.content}}
  </accordion-group>
</accordion>
```

Check out the plnkr demo for full working example code: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/MlcqWL?p=preview

Comment: I had actually copied the example code between the "<accordion>" tags but since the tags themselves were throwing errors, I didn't  bother including it all in my question text.  And yes, I am including Angular above the scripts.  I have updated my question to show this.

Comment: I deleted the other 3 references as suggested, but the tag still shows with the green underlining.  Hovering over it, the message reads"unknown element".

Comment: Also, I tried looking at your Plnkr, but it is empty.  It only says "Hello Plunker"

Comment: fixed the url. So, when you say `the message reads"unknown element"` what are you referring to, your editor?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Visual Studio 2013.  When hover over the "<accordion>"  tag (which has a green squiggly line underneath it), the tip that pops up reads "unknown element".  All of the other Angular in my page works fine.

Comment: Your plnkr is basically the original code that I tried, the problem seems to be that it is not receiving the directive for some reason even though I added the "['ui.bootstrap']" injection in my module and the scripts to the page.  Was I supposed to do something other than just include the script files in my 'Scripts" folder in my project?  I'm new to all of this, so please excuse my ignorance.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about any squiggles in your editor, that won't effect anything. If it really bothers you, there's probably some way to add custom tags to your version of VS2013. This answer seems like it addresses that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25727173/1078450

Comment: I mentioned the "squiggly" only because I thought it might help to explain the problem.  Using your "exact" code from your plnkr, the only thing that works properly in my page is the "add new item" button.  The accordion still does not work at all in my page.  The text for each heading shows, but has no functionality.

Answer (score 0):

What I discovered is that the Accordion feature is not working as expected because my _Layout.cshtml has a nav-sidebar in it.  If I comment out the navbar, the Accordion works as expected.  I plan to post a "new" question regarding the found issue.